# Which is better to find the width of screen

Tags: reactjs, media-queries, frontend, width, material-ui

use media query or windows width : which is better in terms of performance etc.

```
window.innerWidth <= 768;

useMediaQuery(breakpoints.down("sm"));
```

Thank you.

Comment: I think,  if you are working with material-ui, more consistent way will be to use useMediaQuery hook, question of performance less important for current use case

Comment: for what do you want to find width?

Comment: if you want to work with window object you should calc width in this way: ```innerWidth * devicePixelRatio```

Comment: @zemil I want to make some ui changes for only mobile screens.